# VS 2019 : Locals empty when debugging only in part of the code

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug as always in VS 2019. Recently, for some reason, when I hit a breakpoint in specific .cs files the Locals window is empty. However, in other files locals are available! When I use Immediate Window in the files where locals are empty, I get "Unable to evaluate expression". But same command in other parts of the code is working.

Context:

- Project is a C# library (dll) which loads as a plug-in in another application (Revit)
- The pdb file is located in the same directory as the dll
- Project is using Fody Weaver. However I've been using it before and I weren't having debugging issues with it.
- Advanced build settings are as follows:
  [image]
- I attach to the process using Debug > Attach to Process and the Automatic option:
  [image]
- I am attaching in the Debug mode and the dll is built using Debug mode as well.
- The "Optimize Code" option is unchecked.
- Things I have tried:

  - Enabled "Use Managed Compatibility" mode
  - Enabled "Suppress JIT optimization on module load"
  - Enabled "Just My Code"
  - Deleting breakpoints and creating the again
  - Cleaning solution and rebuilding
  - Restarting Visual Studio
  - Starting Visual Studio as an administrator
  - Updating Visual Studio to latest
  - Restarting my computer

**Update:**

I tried refactoring and splitting the file where locals aren't showing, into two files. To my surprise now the locals are showing both in the file where they weren't showing before and in the new file. However, the values shown are still weird. The type of objects are shown as `float {class}` and I can't expand to see their properties. See screenshot below from locals displayed in the new file:

[image]

Comment: If you set the breakpoints in other parts of the code where Locals were available, will Locals available this time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but yes the Locals show in some files when I hit the breakpoint but not in other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case the issue was a virus protection software called Cylance I had installed. I changed its settings to Monitor and in the Debug settings of VS, unchecked the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and the locals are all showing as expected again.